# How to add a separator to a WPF combobox that is databound?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, combobox, separator

Is there any way I can add a seprator into a WPF combobox that is databound?  ie in my xaml, the combobox's ItemsSource="{Binding TheList}".  The list is an observable collection of objects, one of i want separated from the rest.  This list is also generated from sql, so its not hard-coded or anything.  I wouldn't want the seaprator to be selectable, either.  Thanks!

Comment: What you have tried so far to acheive this?

Answer (score 4):

Check [this](http://www.japf.fr/2008/12/how-insert-separator-in-a-databound-combobox/) solution. It uses a `Style` to change the `Template` of certain `ComboBoxItem` objects

Comment: The link is dead. It's always a bad idea to just post a link to other sides. It would be better to include the source codes.

Answer (score 3):

I was building my combo box within the .cs file dynamically and without the use of Bindings, but I believe it could help you. The separators can't be clicked on and selected.

```cs
ComboBox frameColor = new ComboBox()
{
    Width = 200,
    Margin = new Thickness(180, -780, 0, 0),
    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
    IsEditable = false,
    Items =
    {
        new ComboBoxItem(){...},
        new Separator(),
        new ComboBoxItem(){...},
        new ComboBoxItem(){...},
        new ComboBoxItem(){...},
        new Separator(),
        new ComboBoxItem(){...},
        new ComboBoxItem(){...},
        new ComboBoxItem(){...},
        new ComboBoxItem(){...},
        new ComboBoxItem(){...},
    }
```

This is the result:
[image: Combo box with separators]

Answer (score 1):

Although my `ComboxBox` (*at the moment*) is not `DataBound` I achieved the concept of a separator by adding a bottom border to an element. In this example two lines before and two lines after the separator.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Cbx" SelectionChanged="Cbx_SelectionChanged">
  <ComboBoxItem Content="select one..." Foreground="DarkGray" IsSelected="True" /
  <ComboBoxItem Content="ABC" />
  <ComboBoxItem Content="DEF" />
  <ComboBoxItem Content="GHI" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,0,2" />
  <ComboBoxItem Content="KLM" />
  <ComboBoxItem Content="NOP" />
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

XAML only solution for every item. You could probably add triggers based on `ItemsControl` `AlternationCount` if it was always the same list of items.

This is the result.
[image]

```
<ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
  <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkGray" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,1,0,0" />
  </Style>
</ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a ComboBox.ItemTemplate to draw your itens

http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Silverlight-ComboBox.aspx

Comment: this says nothing about a separator

Comment: Could you update the link because it is not working?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the same in C# code:

```
Cbx.Items.Add("ABC");
Cbx.Items.Add("DEF");
ComboBoxItem item = new ComboBoxItem();
item.Content = "GHI";
item.BorderBrush = Brushes.Black;
item.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 2);
Cbx.Items.Add(item);
Cbx.Items.Add("KLM");
Cbx.Items.Add("NOP");
```